# ToTable and ToView in inherits class is throwing: Both '' and '' are mapped to the table ''

Tags: entity-framework-core, .net-6.0

I've created a table and a view that returns the same type, I know that one type should be assigned to one object in DB, so I create a child class, but when I assign the inherited class (**PeriodChild**) I get the error: *Both 'Period' and 'PeriodChild' are mapped to the table 'Periods'. All the entity types in a hierarchy that don't have a discriminator must be mapped to different tables.*

```
public class MyDbContext : DbContext {
    public DbSet<Period> Periods { get; set; }
    public DbSet<PeriodChild> GetPeriods;

    public MyDbContext(DbContextOptions<MyDbContext> dbContextOptions) : base(dbContextOptions) { }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Period>();
        modelBuilder.Entity<PeriodChild>().ToView("GetPeriods"); // CREATE VIEW select Id, DATEADD(day, 1, FromDate) from [Periods]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only add .ToTable(null) or .ToTable((string?)null) *in net-6* to children entity

```
    modelBuilder.Entity<PeriodChild>().ToTable((string?)null).ToView("GetPeriods");
```